# Remove TitleBar from Spark WindowedApplication

Tags: apache-flex, air

How do I remove TitleBar from Spark WindowedApplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `systemChrome` option to `none` in application descriptor to remove system title bar (system border will gone, too). Gray title bar provided by Flex will remain. To hide it too, set showTitleBar="false" in your application.

Comment: Cannot resolve attribute 'showTitleBar' for component type spark.components.WindowedApplication.

Comment: This was answer for Flex 3. In Spark, there is `titleBar` skin part, so I guess you need custom skin for WindowedApplication.